# File input is not working in webview in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have a web view component as

```
<View style={{height: 350}}>
                <WebView
                    source={./index.html} scalesPageToFit
                />
            </View>
```

and I am using the following code to take a file form the user

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input  type='file'/>
</div>
```

but i cannot select any file in android. now pop up appears as in the browsers. I set all the external storage read and write permissions too but no help.

Comment: This is not Right way to upload the file. try this npm package for file upload in react-native
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fileupload